# generating correlated samples

Tags: correlation, covariance, matrix-decomposition

let's say I have `n` correlated variables, from which I would like to sample. I know there are several packages, like `mvrnorm`, utilizing the cholesky decomposition algorithm.

However, would it be possible to decorrelate the variables first using a linear transformation, sample from each 1D distribution and then apply the transposed transformation?

Comment: look at copulas, they generate joint distributions from marginals, which seems to be what you want

Comment: Your proposal makes sense and works for multivariate Normal distributions, but not (in general) for any other distribution.  The reason is that uncorrelated variables still are not (in general) independent, but by "sample from each 1D distribution" strongly implies you are thinking of them as independent.

Comment: Your proposal is in essence what is being done when using Cholesky decomposition to sample from multivariate normal distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Partially answered in comments:
Your proposal is in essence what is being done when using Cholesky decomposition to sample from multivariate normal distribution. – Mark L. Stone

Your proposal makes sense and works for multivariate Normal distributions, but not (in general) for any other distribution. The reason is that uncorrelated variables still are not (in general) independent, but by "sample from each 1D distribution" strongly implies you are thinking of them as independent. – whuber

look at copulas, they generate joint distributions from marginals, which seems to be what you want – Aksakal